# Javascript RegEx Templating Edge Case

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegEx implemented with JavaScript that is close to doing what I want. However, I am having an issue figuring out the last piece which is causing an issue with an edge case. Here is the RegEx that I have so far:

```
/\$\{(.+?(}\(.+?\)|}))/g
```

The idea is that this RegEx would use a templating system to replace/inject variables in a string based on templated variables. Here is an example of the edge case issue:

```
"Here is a template string ${G:SomeVar:G${G:SomeVar:G} that value gets injected in."
```

The problem is the RegEx is matching this:

```
"${G:SomeVar:G${G:SomeVar:G}"
```

What I want it to match is this:

```
"${G:SomeVar:G}"
```

How would I get the RegEx to match the expected variable in this edge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching anything with `(.+?)`, change it to not match another closing brace or dollar sign, `[^{$]`.

```
\$\{([^{$]+?(}\(.+?\)|}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an alternation in your pattern to either stop at `}` or also match a following `(...)` after it.

As the dot can match any character, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching `{` `}` `(` `)`

If you want to match `${G:SomeVar:G}` but also `${G:SomeVar:G}(test)` you can add an optional non capture group after it.

For a match only, you can omit the capture groups.

```
\$\{[^{}]*}(?:\([^()]*\))?
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSRe5V/1).

---

If the format of the string with the `:` and the same character before and after it should be matched, you can use a capture group with a backreference:

```
\$\{([A-Z]):[^{}]*?:\1}(?:\([^()]*\))?
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CEf68k/1).

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. The additional non capture group could be useful.